# Cloudinary responsive image in Bootstrap 4 modal to fit mobile screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cloudinary

I want to use Cloudinary image in Bootstrap 4 modal popup. The modal popup works fine in desktop view eg the modal and image are centered in view area, and modal works as expected.

However, when I test with mobile (in Chrome dev) while modal works fine, the Cloudinary image is not responsively sized no matter what I try so far.

The modal HTML as follows:

```
<!-- Creates the bootstrap modal where the image will appear -->
<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xs">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
            <img src="" class="item_photo_pop img-center cld-responsive">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript for modal as follows:

```
<script>
    
    $(function() {
        $('.item_photo').on('click', function() {
            var src_url = $.cloudinary.url($(this).attr('id'), { width: 'auto', crop: 'scale', secure: true });
            $('.item_photo_pop').attr('src', src_url);
            $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
        });
    });
    
    var cl = cloudinary.Cloudinary.new({cloud_name: "xxxxxxxx"}); 
    cl.responsive();

</script>
```

The css used as follows:

```
.modal-dialog {
    display: table; /* This makes modal fill view area */ 
    width: 95%;
    height: 92%;
    padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
    height: 99%;
}

.img-center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

If I show modal without image eg set `var src_url = ''` then the modal responsively fills view area in both desktop and mobile.

So it is clear that the Cloudinary image is not responsively sizing to fit the modal.

What can I do to get Cloudinary image to responsively size to fit the modal?

Edit to add:

The javascript updates the`img src` url to this: `https://res.cloudinary.com/xxxxxxxx/image/upload/c_scale,w_auto/rcdvyr8meehm8jg`

Answer (score 0):

Have you include the file:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cloudinary-core/2.8.0/cloudinary-core-shrinkwrap.js

Can you try to reproduce it with the following code:

```
<div>
  <img class="cld-responsive" width="480px" data-src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/f_auto,w_auto,c_scale/sample.jpg">
</div>

<footer>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var cl = cloudinary.Cloudinary.new({cloud_name: "demo"}); 
    cl.responsive();
    </script>
</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shirlymanor/yfka2o05/

Comment: I hadn't included `cloudinary-core-shrinkwrap.js` but after doing so, still no change. I then tried with cloudinary sample `img` tag but still no change. My script is at bottom of page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using Bootstrap 4 modals and just used [regular css modals](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) and the cloudinary responsive photos just worked fine!

```
<!-- pop up photo modal -->
<div id="modal01" class="photo-modal" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
    <img src="" id="item_photo_pop" class="w3-modal-content" style="width:100%">
  </div>

</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.item_photo').on('click', function() {
            var src_url = $.cloudinary.url($(this).attr('id') + '.jpg', { width: 'auto', crop: 'scale', secure: true});
            $('#item_photo_pop').attr('src', src_url);
            $('#modal01').attr("style", "display:block");
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var cl = cloudinary.Cloudinary.new({cloud_name: "demo"}); 
    cl.responsive();
</script>
```